# Chilkat SQL not working/returning anything

Tags: sql, chilkat

I am trying 30 days free trial of Chilkat and I am not getting any results in SQL, nor error information (unless it is a string text value, hardcoded). I have installed the module on the server and it confirms correctly

For example this piece of code with obviously incorrect address just runs through without any feedback (the code is from their tutorial - apart from the address  - so should be technically correct)

```
 DECLARE @hr int
    DECLARE @iTmp0 int
    DECLARE @sTmp0 nvarchar(max)

    DECLARE @rest int
    EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'Chilkat_9_5_0.Rest', @rest OUT
    IF @hr <> 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Failed to create ActiveX component'
        RETURN
    END

    -- Connect to the REST server.
    DECLARE @bTls int
    SELECT @bTls = 1
    DECLARE @port int
    SELECT @port = 443
    DECLARE @bAutoReconnect int
    SELECT @bAutoReconnect = 1
    DECLARE @success int
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @rest, 'Connect', @success OUT, 'www.incorrect_address.co', @port, @bTls, @bAutoReconnect

    IF @success <> 1
      BEGIN
        EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @rest, 'LastErrorText', @sTmp0 OUT
        PRINT @sTmp0
        EXEC @hr = sp_OADestroy @rest
        RETURN
      END
```

the Global Unlock method returns message that it is working

```
'Unlocked in trial mode.'
```

do you have any idea why it does not work? Any messages hardcoded (like 'unlocked in trial mode') are working but anything that should return values of objects - does not.

I have of course enabled Configuration option 'Ole Automation Procedures' in SQL

Slav

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the LastErrorText property is likely too large for limits imposed by sp_OAGetProperty.  Try using a temp table like this:

```
   DECLARE @tmp1 TABLE (lastErrText ntext)
   INSERT INTO @tmp1 EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @rest, 'LastErrorText'
   SELECT * from @tmp1
```